# Format JSON data in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, c#-4.0

I need JSON data in a format like `data: { MyClass0: {somedata}, MyClass1: {somedata} }`.

But I am getting data in the format `data: { MyClass: {somedata}, MyClass: {somedata} }`.

MyClass is a class in which I have created some properties.

Here is my classes file:

```
public class data {
    data(MyClass _myClass) {
        subData = _myClass;
    }
    public MyClass subData { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass {
    public value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my WebMethod

```
foreach(var d in rows) {
    list.add(new data(new MyClass(d)));
}

return new data {
    subData = list
};
```

Comment: what are you using now?  what have you tried?  How about a `StringBuilder?`

Comment: i have two classes (data, MyClass), in data class i have created a property of type List<MyClass>.

Comment: a `List<MyClass>` will generally be represented as an array of objects in JSON

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the examples that you have given are valid JSON. Valid examples would be

```
// MyClass0 and MyClass1 each an object value
{ "data" : { "MyClass0" : {}, "MyClass1" : {} } }

// MyClass' value is an array of objects
{ "data" : { "MyClass" : [{}, {}] } }
```

The **[JSON specification](http://json.org/)** stipulates that there should be key/value pairs and keys should be enclosed in double quotes (in addition, so too must string values).

How are you generating the JSON string? Three of the more popular options are

1. **[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)**
2. **[DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)**
3. **[JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)**.

Comment: I have webmethod of type data, and in ajax call which converted to json object.

Comment: public class data{
    public List<MyClass> MyClass { get; set; }
}

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal you can edit the question to add in the relevant code. I would expect that class structure to produce JSON that matches my second example. Then it's a simple case of looping over the array to get the objects.